# Prevent horizontal scrolling outside out main content area

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar

So I have a page where the header image can be wider than the width of the content. Say, the content is always 960px wide, but the header image could 1200px wide.

So in order to keep the header image centred I'm using the left: +/-50% trick.

```
<div class="page">
  <header>
      <div class="image"><img /></div>
  </header>
  <article>lots of text...</article>
<div>

div.page {
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
}

header {
  height: 75px;
}

div.image {
      position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  background: green;
}

article {
  background: yellow;
}
```

So as in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P7F7j/ you can see that horizontal scroll bars display because `div.image` is off screen, and the same would happen if `img` is off screen too. Is there any way to remove these elements from the flow so they don't trigger horizontal scrolling?

Comment: The containing div could use overflow-x: hidden;. Edit: not getting the scrollbars in the fiddle, though...

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan Hmm that does work in the fiddle, but not the project I'm working on, I've obviously missed something in my simplification. Thanks.

Comment: try position: relative; and overflow: hidden; for header

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan: Oh I get scroll bars, however I'm using a magic mouse on OSX 10.8, so I really have no idea where scroll bars are!

Comment: Do you have a live site anywhere we can check?

Comment: Unfortunately not, quite in the infant stages. @Horen's answer has done me well though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the header `min-width: 960px; width: 100%;` and set the image as a `background-image` with style `no-repeat center top`

That way the header will always be at least 960px and will be filled with your image. Overflowing is handled automatically with background-images.

Comment: Oh, I like this one, I'll try it. Thanks.